# Is there a name for this server-side HTML indentation style?

Tags: html, code-formatting

I have seen an indentation style - a methodology really - whereby the logic is indented totally **separately** from the HTML. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
<div>
if(something) {
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
    if(someOtherThing) {
                <div>

                </div>  
    }
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
}
</div>
```

...as *opposed* to:

```
<div>
    if(something) {
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    if(someOtherThing) {
                        <div>

                        </div>  
                    }
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Is there a **name** for this indentation style/methodology?

Comment: That is quite smart, actually

Comment: I agree. I'm going to start trying to get my team to use it, and it would be helpful be able to point to a named methodology out there. I propose "Separate Indentation".

Comment: I am not sure what this style is called, but it is generally used for conditional loading of html elements. It is pretty similar to Angular, React and embedded JavaScript code. 

Refer this: https://medium.com/@atingenkay/getting-started-with-ejs-28fe4a693e53